# Need Hybris Extension Name

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex, hybris-data-hub

```
https://hybrismart.com/2016/10/14/managing-localized-messages-via-backoffice/
```

From above link, May I know whats the Hybris extension name for HybrisResource and HybrisResourceItem classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are new item types. You need to create them.

Comment: https://hybrismart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2016-10-10_15h15_28.png

May I know how to achieve this?

Comment: and may I know where can i find ready made code for above requirement, so I can use it directly.

Comment: If you are hybris developer, yes you must know how to create new items. If you need working extension you can direct contact with hybrismart or hire hybris developer.